# PostgreSQL location with Postgres.app

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

I am using the [postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/). I get a terminal window when I start the postgres app. However, when I go into a bash shell and type in `psql` it says `Command not found`. I assume the path to the app is not set in my profile. How can I find out where the postgres.app is located and how do I tell that my profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set your `$PATH` up.

This is covered [on the Postgres.app website](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html).

```
Add this to your ~/.bash_profile:

export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

... then reopen your shell/terminal.